# git branch (no branch)

Tags: git

well, i have just made a huge mistake.

I am working on a project, and thought i was working in the master branch.
So i added the files i needed, commited them and when i tried to push to origin i got

```
Everything is up to date
```

I used `git branch` and got

```
* (no branch)
* master
```

So, in stress, i stashed the pending changes in (no branch) and checked out master.
Now i lost all my changes, because i can't checkout the branch "that shall not be named". When i list the branches i only have

```
* master
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You haven't lost the changes if they were committed. You just don't have a named reference to them.

Try running `git reflog` and look for a line near the top that will say something like `checkout: moving from <commit-id> to master`. You can then use that `<commit-id>` to create a temp branch to inspect your changes and bring them over to the `master` branch:

```
git checkout -b temp-branch <commit-id>
```

You can merge this branch, or just cherry-pick the necessary commits.

I hope this helps.

Comment: `git reflog` is a lifesaver :)

Comment: you also do not loose changes if the changed files were staged (the changes must not be commited necessarily). you can still recover the regarding dangling blobs.